# Can someone help me solve this exercise on programming with C language on Dev-C++?

Tags: c

Write a program that reads numbers until you read the number 999 then the process stops reading. Therefore use do while. Then display the sum of two digit numbers, both positive and negative that were imported in the computer and the number of numbers that were imported to the computer overall.

When I insert the number 999 the process stops. That works fine.
I'm sure that the if command is wrong cause it doesn't add any numbers in sum.
I run it and it prints out that the sum of the two digit numbers is 0.

```
int num1, a, sum;
a = 0;
sum = 0;

do
{
   printf("give number\n");
   scanf("%d", &num1);
   a = a + 1;

   if ((num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99))
   {      
       sum = sum + num1; 
   }

   printf("the sum of the two digit numbers is %d\n", sum);
}

while (num1 != 999);

printf("the sum of the two digit numbers is %d\n", athr);
printf("the number of numbers that were inserted overall is %d\n", a);
```

Comment: I can help you by suggesting you don't use DevC++, which is a big pile of pooh - use Code::Blocks at http://www.codeblocks.org/.

Comment: Yep, completely agree. Don't use DevC++.

Comment: I have to use dev c++. That what they told us at school.

Comment: Code::Blocks is (kind of) an updated version of DevC++, if it's at all possible to use it (maybe on your home computer?) I would suggest doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99)
```

How can a number satisfy all these conditions ? For instance, `(num1<=-10) && (num1>=10)` think of a number which can satisfy these two conditions ?

Answer (score 6):

Your `if` statement can never be true:

```
if ((num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99))
```

since the two valid ranges don't overlap and you're using `&&` to 'combine' them.

Use

```
if (((-99 <= num1) && (num1 <= -10)) || ((10 <= num1) && (num1 <= 99)))
```

instead.

---

My readability tip of they day: note that I slightly rejiggered the comparisons. The range comparisons mirror a little more closely how they might look in algebraic notation:

```
(-99 <= num1 <= -10) or (10 <= num1 <= 99)
```

It's a small thing, but I find it makes a big difference to being able to follow the logic of these kinds of tests. Just don't fall into the trap of coding this:

```
if ((-99 <= num1 <= -10) || (10 <= num1 <= 99))
```

Which, unfortunately, is syntactically valid in C/C++ but will not give you the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

Can `num1` be both <-10 and >10 ?

Comment: It can if your quantum computer exposes the superposition on the sign qubit. :)

Comment: unfortunately DevC++ doesn't support quantum compilation. You have to use Turbo-C for that...  :P

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i saw what i did wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Your condition

```
(num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99)
```

can never be `true`, because no number can both be negative (`<=-10`) *and* positive (`>=10`).

Answer (score 1):

You messed up the check for two-digitness:

You did

```
(-99 <= n <= -10) AND (10 <= n <= 99)
```

You should have done

```
(-99 <= n <= -10) OR (10 <= n <= 99)
```

(Or is `||` in C)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your if statement.  Let's try it with 2 arbitrary 2 digit numbers.  -42 and 42.

For negative 42:

```
   true            true           false        false

((num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99))
```

Positive 42:

```
   false          false           true         true

((num1>=-99) && (num1<=-10) && (num1>=10) && (num1<=99))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you include math.h, you could simplify this to:

```
if (fabs(num1) >= 10 && fabs(num1) <= 99){
    sum = sum + num1;
}
```

Although I'm guessing C++ also has support for += as well.

Comment: Well, I tried compiling it online and it seemed to work. I'm pretty inexperienced with C++, so it may not be the best solution.